# Create Tree With Oracle ADF

Tags: tree, oracle-adf

I want to create a tree with Oracle ADF using this tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/fusionapps.1111/e15524/ui_impl_appfeat_ttt.htm#BABDBBDI) .After creating the tree ,  I want to add CREATE and DELETE button to this tree .
In the mentioned tutorial document  , it says if you want to create these buttons , you must  go to the CONFIGURE TREE PATTERNS window .
I do not know where it is .
Can any one help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are doing "general purpose" ADF Faces development? Please note the link you reference, is docs for Fusion Applications *specifically* - not "general purpose' ADF development. "Oracle® Fusion Applications Developer's Guide
11g Release 1 (11.1.2)

Therefore, there are different components that you use for a tree: "Application Tree" - which is not the same as an ADF Faces Tree, [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FE21764_01%2Fapirefs.1111%2Fe12419%2Ftagdoc%2Faf_tree.html&ei=0seyU9C7JYj_oQTl4ILIDw&usg=AFQjCNG8cwg1HOei7SWI7yxa5aP24Gwxdw&sig2=_zYJoUPAvrAFN4X5iA9w0w&bvm=bv.70138588,d.cGU).
I think this is why you can't find it.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your answer ....
When i read this site (Binaries: CRUD operations on a tree table) , i do not know where can i use this code .
should i create a button and in BUTTON ACTION , ACTION LISTENER introduce createChildren method (method that is implement on link above ) , then in java class of this action listener createChildren method ?
Please help me

Comment: i do not understand what you are doing.  I answered your question, did I not?